# Is there a way to combine these queries

Tags: sql

Is is efficient to combine two queries into one? What are advantages or disadvantages?
Can someone help me combine these two queries:

```
SELECT quiz_id from questions WHERE question = 10

SELECT quiz_number FROM quizzes WHERE quiz_id = 5
```

quiz_id has 1 to many relationship with question. So for one specific question there will be only one quiz_id, but one quiz_id can have up to 20 question under it.

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to combine (unless there is a relationship between the two tables)

Comment: Could you provide the layout of your tables and the logic involved?  As it is, the idea of asking for the quiz_id where 'question = 10', to me, implies you're grabbing the ID for every quiz which has a tenth question.  The purpose of that seems odd.  However, if questions have unique IDs across all quizzes (that is, thers is a one-to-one question-to-quiz_id mapping), this makes much more sense.

Comment: @Gurnor It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Is the value `5` in the second query really a compile-time constant or is it the result from the first query?

Comment: @Conspicuous - quiz_id has 1 to many relationship with questions. So for one specific question there will be only one quiz_id, but one quiz_id can have up to 20 questions under it.

Comment: @Gurnor: There's still some information necessary for this to be clear.  Say you have one quiz (quiz_id = 1) with three questions (question = 1...3) and you have a second quiz (quiz_id = 2) also with three question.  Will quiz_id's questions be number 1..3 as well?  Or will they be 4..6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by *combine*, perhaps you mean subselect / subquery? In that case try:

```
---    IN syntax
SELECT quiz_number FROM quizzes WHERE quiz_id IN
       (SELECT quiz_id FROM questions WHERE question = 10);

---    = syntax. This will work only if the subquery returns one value 
SELECT quiz_number FROM quizzes WHERE quiz_id = 
       (SELECT quiz_id FROM questions WHERE question = 10);
```

Comment: The operation you're looking for is the `INNER JOIN`. Don't use `IN` for these things.

Comment: @Tomalak: Why? If he wants to retrieve fileds form `quizzes` only, `IN` or `EXISTS` is more appropriate than `JOIN` (unless one uses MySQL where `x IN (SELECT y FROM z)` is not (yet) quite fully optimized).

Comment: @Joel: `quizid IN (SELECT...)` and `quizid = (SELECT...)` are both valid SQL syntax and work in both Postgres and MySQL.

Comment: They have different meaning (and results) though. And the second expects one row only from the sub-select or a runtime error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the relationship from your 2 posted queries, and that the value 5 in the second query is the result from the first query:

```
SELECT quiz_number FROM quizzes qz
INNER JOIN questions qu on qu.quiz_id = qz.quiz_id
WHERE question = 10
```

Comment: i am using MYSQL i tried both in and inner join queries... Inner join is taking .00002 seconds more than in statement connecting both queries.

Comment: ".00002 seconds more" - really. don't worry no human will be able to tell the difference

Comment: i know just saying... i am new to this i am not sure what is better or used more... If you can tell me that be great?

Answer (score 0):

you can use aliases

```
SELECT question.quiz_id, quiz.quiz_number from questions question,quizzes quiz WHERE question.question = 10 and quiz.quiz_id =5
```